# Adapt an Urlview Iphone5 and 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

This is the code that work on iphone4 in ladscape mode, but in iphone5 give two black strip lateral. Thanks in advance!

CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(-80, 80, 480, 320);
    viewRot.bounds = contentRect;